# I erroneously raised a "Duplicate" flag on a post, but I can't retract the flag — is this a bug?

Tags: support, bug

I raised a duplicate flag on [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90222), but as the OP pointed out the [question I had linked to](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44823) wasn't actually a duplicate of their question.

However, when I clicked on the "flag" link there was no "retract" option. I've deleted the associated comment, but the flag remains.

Is there a reason that type of flag can't be retracted?

Is there anything else I should do (other than being more careful in the future)?

Screenshot of the pop-up:[image: screenshot of flagging pop-up with no "retract" button]
(Note: The message about declined flags wasn't there yesterday when I tried this so that isn't relevant.)

Comment: I can't test this anymore, since my mod privileges close questions immediately, but according to this post on meta, it should be possible to retract your flag by going back to the flag dialogue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295182/i-flag-as-duplicate-op-edits-how-do-i-retract

Comment: @Chris — Yes I tried that, but the option isn't available. I've updated my post to include a screenshot . Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure why you were flagging the question rather than voting to close. I see one close vote on that question; if that’s yours you should be able to retract it from the “close” menu (not the “flag” menu).

Comment: @canadianer — I don't have sufficient reputation to cast close votes ...

Comment: My apologies, I did not realize. Perhaps this is a bug then, or rather an oversight. I wonder if the current close vote was auto-generated by your flag, or if it is someone else’s.

Comment: @canadianer —No problem! Someone had upvoted the associated comment and the flag is labelled as "helpful" so I guess someone else must have mistakenly thought my flag was appropriate and voted to close.

Comment: It looks like what happened here is that the flag got handled (dismissed) before you could retract it.  You can only retract flags when they are active.

Comment: @BrianNickel — Thank you for looking into this, but when I look at my flag history that flag is marked as "helpful" ... is that consistent with the flag being dismissed?

Comment: @tyersome Helpful is a completion status.  Flags in the helpful or unhelpful/declined status are dismissed and no longer active.  This is sometimes but not always combined with some other moderator action.

Comment: @BrianNickel — Ok, I see dismissed ≠ declined. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your flag was handled by the 'Community' user as helpful.

When you flag that a post should be closed but don't have close privileges, it puts the question into the Close Votes queue. If another user sees the entry in the Close Votes queue and decides to vote to close for reason of the dupe you marked, the flag is considered 'helpful' and disappears, and instead there is now a Close Vote from that user.

Looks like that's what happened in this case. Basically, your flag doesn't exist anymore but there is still one vote from a different user to close the question as a duplicate according to your initial flag reason.

It's possible you can see some of this flow if you look at the Timeline for the post: https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/90222/timeline (or click the little 'clock' icon below the down vote link), I'm not sure what exactly non-moderators see and don't see there as far as their own actions.